# Python ctypes: structure with bit fields initialization

Tags: python, structure, ctypes, bit-fields

I noticed that I cannot default initialize an object of ctypes.Structure derived class when it has bit fields in it, but I can default initialize an array of such objects.

Let's say we define such a class:

```
class What(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_float), ('y', ctypes.c_short, 2)]

    def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
        if not x:
            x = ctypes.c_float()
        if not y:
            y = ctypes.c_short()
        super(What, self).__init__(x, y)
```

Now this code executes smoothly and to my understanding, it makes use of the default constructor defined above.

```
what_arr = What * 4
w_arr = what_arr()
```

An array of zero-filled structs is returned. However, when I try to initialize just one object, I get an 'access violation reading location' error and the program crashes.

```
w = What()
```

It would be great if someone explained what is going under the hood and what is the reason for this behavior.

A couple more details:

I need to have

```
x = ctypes.c_float()
y = ctypes.c_short()
```

instead of directly passing 0s to initialization, because normally fields of the structure contain other structures and I want to use their default constructors here too (so that everything is recursively initialized with 0s).

I believe that this may be useful for people who want to test some wrapped package with dummy values first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base class doesn't know what `x` and `y` are.  If I understand the OP correctly the default behavior of `ctypes.Structure` is all that is needed.  I added a `__repr__` function to more easily see what is happening:

```
class What(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_float), ('y', ctypes.c_short, 2)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'What(x={self.x},y={self.y})'
```

Testing...

```
>>> w = What()
>>> w
What(x=0.0,y=0)
>>> w = What(1.5)
>>> w
What(x=1.5,y=0)
>>> w = What(1.5,2)
>>> w
What(x=1.5,y=-2)
>>> wa = (What*4)()
>>> list(wa)
[What(x=0.0,y=0), What(x=0.0,y=0), What(x=0.0,y=0), What(x=0.0,y=0)]
```

Note also that ctypes structures are zero-initialized by default, so you don't need any magic here either even for nested structures:

```
import ctypes

class Inner(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a',ctypes.c_int),('b',ctypes.c_int)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Inner(a={self.a},b={self.b})'

class What(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', Inner), ('y', ctypes.c_short, 2)]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'What(x={self.x},y={self.y})'
```

Testing...

```
>>> w = What()
>>> w
What(x=Inner(a=0,b=0),y=0)
>>> wa = (What*4)()
>>> list(wa)
[What(x=Inner(a=0,b=0),y=0), What(x=Inner(a=0,b=0),y=0), What(x=Inner(a=0,b=0),y=0), What(x=Inner(a=0,b=0),y=0)]
```

Comment: Oh my. Thank you very much. Do you have any explanation for previous behaviour of constructor when bit fields are used vs are not? Can it be that __init__ method is passed already constructed ctypes.c_short object that cannot be resized or something alike?

Comment: @JakubŁanecki You're previous constructor was calling `super()` on the base class which doesn't know about `x` and `y`.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. When I remove bit field specifications from _fields_ both initialization of single object as well as an array work perfectly, issue arises with bit fields only. Also, I believe it suffices to give `super()` the name of child class (that's what we do) for it to know about `x` and `y`.